# rvest scraping data from a button style tag?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Following up with more delving into scraping data off sites. Trying to pull data off of this site seatgeeks to get a few columns. I'm having trouble accessing the pricing and link data specifically. The following code runs well but I can't get accurate data for pricing and for links. 65$ keeps repeating itself even though the numbers are different per button. Any ideas? Appreciate the help!

```
#ticket scruber
library(rvest)

tix_link = paste("https://seatgeek.com/new-york-knicks-tickets#events")
tix_info = tix_link %>% read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(".event-listing-title span")
link_date = read_html(tix_link)
link_date = html_nodes(link_date, ".event-listing-date")
link_time = read_html(tix_link)
link_time = html_nodes(link_time, ".event-listing-time")
link_price = read_html(tix_link)
link_price = html_node(link_price, ".event-listing-button")
link_info = read_html(tix_link)
link_info = html_node(link_info, "span")




#convert to data frame
ticket_deals = data.frame(deals = html_text(tix_info),
                          date = html_text(link_date),
                          time = html_text(link_time),
                          price = html_text(link_price),
                          correpsonding_link = html_attr(link_info,"href"))

head(ticket_deals)

                                      deals                                 date
1       Dallas Mavericks at New York Knicks \n                Nov 14            
2        Detroit Pistons at New York Knicks \n                Nov 16            
3          Atlanta Hawks at New York Knicks \n                Nov 20            
4 Portland Trail Blazers at New York Knicks \n                Nov 22            
5      Charlotte Hornets at New York Knicks \n                Nov 25            
6  Oklahoma City Thunder at New York Knicks \n                Nov 28            
                                        time                                      price
1 \n                Mon  7:30 PM             \n                    From $65            
2 \n                Wed  7:30 PM             \n                    From $65            
3 \n                Sun 12:00 PM             \n                    From $65            
4 \n                Tue  7:30 PM             \n                    From $65            
5 \n                Fri  7:30 PM             \n                    From $65            
6 \n                Mon  7:30 PM             \n                    From $65            
  correpsonding_link
1               <NA>
2               <NA>
3               <NA>
4               <NA>
5               <NA>
```

Comment: _"(e) you shall not use any manual or automated software, devices or other processes (including but not limited to spiders, robots, scrapers, crawlers, avatars, data mining tools or the like) to “scrape” or download data from any web pages contained in the Site or any SeatGeek Offering"_

Comment: Oh i missed that. I was hoping to just keep track of cheap tickets. Thanks for the heads up!